# how to prevent recycling of viewpager in listview item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-linearlayout

I have a listview with viewpager(loads images asynchronously) in each list item. Since listview recycles images on scroll viewpager instantiates again as item goes off the screen. I have also considered using LinearLayout with adapter to populate instead of listview to prevent views recycling, but im not sure it could hold large data lists. any help??

Comment: why do you not want the views to be recycled?

Comment: as i mentioned, my listitem has viewpgager which loads images remotely . If item goes offscreen , viewpager adapter re-instantiates which makes images loaded every time an item is recycled. this makes my lisview scroll laggy. Hope I am clear!!

Answer (score 1):

You are clear, and what is more clear is that your architecture is terribly wrong…

The reason why the views get recycled is not because Android wants you to do extra work, it's because on a Mobile device, memory is LIMITED. If something is not visible, it should go away (most of the time).

You can increase the ViewPager offset a little bit more if you want something to stay for longer but the truth is that your image loading library should cache the images to the point where the next time you recreate them, they are instantly available, if there's memory to keep the cache alive or they should be simply re-downloaded. Welcome to Mobile Development.

Take a look at [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for example (on how to load images and cache them the right way).

Comment: increasing viewpager offset wont stop listitem being recycled, my problem is the listitem hosting viewpager view whose adapter gets created in getview method of list adapter and I am curious about any alternative for this. I am using  Android-Universal-Image-Loader library which is probably best in category. Anyways thx for your kind suggestions!!

Comment: You will have to post some more code because what you're reading sounds very spaghetti :)

Comment: My point is, it is the purpose of a listview (and the corresponding adapter) to Recycle views, it was the reason why it was created and heavily optimized. Attempting to prevent that makes (to me) no sense and makes me wonder why are you having this problem in the first place.